# Showing UserControl once at the time with DataTemplateSelector

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, datatemplateselector

I have a couple specific user controls to Show some Content, e.g. simple like Image, WebControl but also two complex specific custom controls drawing on a canvas.

Now I thought using the DataTemplateSelector to handle the different UserControls. I actully used this http://tech.pro/tutorial/807/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector as a reference.

I changed the code so the form loads the UserControls dynamically (according to the file extension) in the following collection:

```
ObservableCollection<string> _pathCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

The only difference to the reference is now I want to navigate back and forward to the next control by showing one control only at the time. Which control should I use instead of ListView?

```
<Grid>
    <ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=PathCollection}" 
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource imgStringTemplateSelector}">
    </ListView>
 </Grid>
```

How do I need to bind it to the template (equal to ItemTemplateSelector above)? WPF is still very new to me and I am learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ContentControl. Bind your current item to the Content-property and the DataTemplateSelector to the ContentTemplateSelector-property.

```xml
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentItem, Mode=OneWay}", ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource imgStringTemplateSelector}" />
```

Your CurrentItem should be a DependencyProperty or a INotifyPropertyChanged-property of your DataContext. When you change your CurrentItem, the ContentControl will update the template automatically with help of your TemplateSelector.

Comment: Thx, that worked. But small correction so it works ('This' is the name of the current window): <ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=This, Path=CurrentItem, Mode=OneWay}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource imgStringTemplateSelector}" />